# How to start GPS tracking triggered by a iBeacon in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, gps, background-process, ibeacon

I am working on an app that records journeys by tracking the GPS. Everything is working fine in background **if we start the process from the foreground** (by tapping the button "Start Journey").
Now the idea is start record these journeys automatically triggered by a iBeacon. When the iPhone gets inside of a beacon region, the app is detecting this and calls the function `LocationManager.StartUpdatingLocation();`

**PROBLEM:**
Using iBeacons from background, we only get 10 seconds ranging and that is the same figure I have got to get location updates from GPS.

All I need is detect I am inside of beacon region, start GPS and keep it running, and only disable the GPS when I am outside of the region.

Comment: I've been trying many thing like this, but until now I was never able to start the GPS location fix from the background.

Comment: Have you tried with background long running tasks? I am thinking to go by this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually recently wanted to implement this behavior in one of our apps too, and found that if we start significant location updates ([`startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges)) in the foreground, then we're able to start regular location updates (`startUpdatingLocation`) in the background, in our `didEnterRegion` implementation.

(Naturally, your app needs the "always" authorization to access Location Services, and the "Location updates" Background Mode enabled.)

Our app is still pending review, so whether that's a bug or a feature of Core Location, and whether Apple is okay with that, remains to be seen.

Comment: Thank you! Well, we have also this implementation and seems to work (in foreground). The problem we have got is when you start the process from the background. Eg: The iPhone is in stand by and when you have entered in a beacon region the app should start record a new journey until you left from the region.
Is your app working fine in background as well?

Comment: Yes, **with significant location updates turned on**, our app can start location updates in the background, and continue ranging until we stop it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The app is now recording journeys even in background (as expected). I also forgot to set the new permission `AllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true` for **iOS9**

Comment: Checking the log files, I noticed the app is ranging the beacon all the time! I thought that this should stop after the 10 seconds.

Comment: It usually stops after 10 seconds because didEnter/didExit only wake up the app for 10 seconds—and ranging only works when the app is running (foreground or background). After 10 secs, the app goes back to the suspended state. But with background location updates running, the app doesn't go to sleep until you stop the location updates, so you can keep ranging. Just keep the battery drain in mind—you're actually required to include a warning about that in your app's description on iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can use `CoreLocation` geofences in the background, but you can't get fine GPS updates continually.  This isn't a Xamarin thing -- it is an iOS restriction.

I wrote the blog post that @RobertN referenced about extending background beacon ranging to 3 minutes.  But I don't think this is much help to you because you want to do get GPS updates continually, which Apple simply does not allow.

Comment: " but you can't get fine GPS updates continually. " wrong you can. But you have to start that from foreground and you must use that locations somehow. My app gets gps with maximum precision in background, But in his case he cannot because he wants to start that from background

Comment: @davidgyoung Did not realize that was your blog posting. I have used it as a reference for others for awhile now, it saved my bacon on a contract project earlier this year. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found it helpful!

Comment: @davidgyoung As AlexWien said, I can get GPS updates continually, if you start the process from the foregound. In this case my APP is working fine. The point know is if there is any way to get the same approach but starting the process from the background (automatically). Eg: start collection coordinates when you enter in a beacon region until you left the region. This is really useful as the users always forgot to open the app to "click" start record journey.

Comment: If you request location background mode in your Info.plist, and combine it with the extending background ranging technique in my blog post, you can get GPS updates indefinitely in the background.  It may, however, make it harder to get your app approved for the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

The best explanation to this I seen can extend that 10 seconds to 3 minutes, but that is it... App rejection is an issue with continuous background operation unless your app truly is reviewed as a Navigation app:

> A second approach involves tracking the beacon in the background,
>   noting its estimated distance, and only triggering an action when the
>   beacon is estimated to be within a specific range. This approach is
>   problematic on iOS, because CoreLocation generally allows only 10
>   seconds of ranging time when an app is in the background. If a beacon
>   is first detected at 50 meters, and a person is approaching the beacon
>   at one meter per second, the mobile device will still be 40 meters
>   away when iOS suspends the app and stops it from ranging.
>
> The good news is that it is possible to extend background ranging time
>   on iOS. If your app is a navigation app, you can specify location
>   updates in the “Required background modes” in your Info.plist. But
>   this approach makes it harder to get AppStore approval -- you have to
>   convince reviewers that your app is providing navigation services to
>   the user. This probably isn’t true for many apps that simply want to
>   use beacons to trigger at a specific distance.
>
> Fortunately, you can still extend background ranging time without
>   requesting special background modes. The time you can get is limited
>   -- only three minutes. But this clock restarts each time your app is woken up in the background, meaning you can get an extra three minutes
>   of ranging time each time your app detects a beacon (enters a beacon
>   region) or stops seeing beacons (exits a beacon region.)

Via: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html