# Xamarin iOS run a Long Running Task background forever

Tags: ios, xamarin, background-process

I need to run a task in background to check the current settings in the app every hour (needs to read the scheduler and enabled/disable services). At the moment I added a **Long Running task** but this is killed by iOS after 3 minutes.

```
public async Task Start (){     
    var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource ();

    var taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask ("LongRunningTask", OnExpiration);

    try 
    {
        await DoWork(cancelToken.Token);
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    {
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested) 
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LongRunningTask Cancelled");
        }
    }

    UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask (taskId);
}
```

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Larcerax Could you give me an example in Swift?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't do swift and I won't even attempt to help you with ojbecitve-c, it will required more than 1 day of time to make you understand how it works and why you shoudl never use Xamarin. first off, check how many questions have been answered about Xamarin. and then ask yourself if its worth it. Just learn IOS the right way and be done

Comment: That wasn't the question. The question is whether it is possible and if I am doing something wrong? I think you can read the code above.

Comment: This is a common thing in backgrounding on iOS, the 3 minute limit can be extended to 10 minutes but getting it to run 'forever'....well unless you are submitting something 'like' a navigation app and get Apple to review it as such, the odds are it would be rejected... Long time ago people would play silent .mp3s to force iOS to continue app background execution, but all those tricks are invalid nowadays. Check out this and the linked blog post http://stackoverflow.com/a/33696789/4984832

Comment: And this has nothing to do with using Xamarin's Mono runtime or `native` ObjC/Swift, iOS backgrounding is iOS backgrounding...language independent

Comment: In this case is a navigation app. The options **Enable background Modes** and **Location updates** was already approved.

Comment: Cool, you are already using the Core Location framework, your app will be awoken when significant-changes occur to the devices' location assuming you are using that newer service (recommended). But if you are using the older `Standard Location Service` it will not... remember that service can be paused by iOS and will send you an 'event' via the delegate you registered to locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates... And using that service your app will NOT be resumed... but using the significant change Location service your app will be relaunched, just like if using Region Monitoring/iBeacon...

Comment: @Larcerax There is *zero* reason why you have to use Objective C when writing iOS applications these days. Code written in Swift or Xamarin (C#) will work just as well and is just as fast as Objective C. There is no difference - it all gets compiled to binary code. The OS has no idea which language the app was coded in as this is all compiled code which calls the exact same iOS APIs. Just because the OS itself is written in Objective C, it doesn't mean the apps have to be.

Comment: @RobertN I am using the newer service `CLLocationManager` and actually using `locationManager.StartMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges ()` can be a really good idea. I will test that. Thanks!

Comment: @gjfonte Great, just remember that if location changes are not occurring, then your original question of "every hour" might not happen as the person/device could be static for X amount of time... BTW: When we need to run a task on a long term schedule, we 'ping' the device with a background notification that is registered to an app, that awakens the app in the background, the background async task is launched by us and we get 3 minutes to perform our actions...in our case, really simple callback back to our servers to insure that the device is still active and functional (it is an unattended k

Comment: @NickG wrong, doing things outside of Objective-C and Switft is just stupid, it's not that hard to learn IOS stuff the right way. I'm adamant about just how stupid 3rd party solutions are. They don't make anyone's job easier and they in fact complicate it since there's very few questions answered about Xamarin problems. Xamarin is a waste of time and is entirely worthless. I hope this company and BS like "lol REACT" from Facebook die very soon, they product misaligned expectations and sh&*tty apps.

Comment: @gjfonte: Did you menage to get this to work?

Comment: @JohnCogan I haven't done yet. I will implement (soon) and see if it works.